# Mapping of a child component improperly updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a situation where I am mapping an array in a component. Inside the map return, a child component is rendered for each item in the map, using the value from the array. When I add an element to this array (using splice() to PUSH (not replace) an item) the map re-renders but the child component does not seem to pick up on this new value in its state variables initial value. This is hard to explain so let me write pseudo code.

**Parent component:**

```
export const Parent = () => {
       const [array, setArray] = useState<>([0,1,2,3,4]);

       const addThing = (index: number) => {
         const num = 5;

          let newArray = [...array];
          newArray.splice(index+ 1, 0, num);
          setArray(newArray);
  };

       {array.map((elem, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i}>
                  <Child
                    theThing={elem}
                  />

                 <button onClick={()=> addThing(i)}> add a thing </button>
              </div>
            );
          })}{" "}


}
```

**Child component:**

```
export const Child = ({theThing}) => {
       const [thing, setThing] = useState<>(theThing);

       console.log(thing);

}
```

So the issue here is that when I click that "add a thing" button, it will add the thing to the array but the console.log will spit out what the value of the array item right after it was instead of "5".

Example: we have array [0,1,2,3,4]
upon calling addThing(2)
We should get the logging [0,1,2,5,3,4]
but I see [0,1,2,3,3,4]

Note that the EXPECTED value IS in the actual array, it is just upon entering the child that it doesn't set the state to the passed in "theThing".

Answer (score 1):

There are two factors in why the `Child` value is not updated:

1. You are using the array index (`i`) as the key for the element wrapping your `Child`
2. The `Child` only uses the passed `theThings` as the *initial* state

The root of your issue is the first one (using the array index `i` as the key). This key is how React knows which element is the same across renders, so when when you insert a new element at index 2 the old `Child` with key `2` is reused and since the prop `theThing` is only used as initial state in the child, this value will not be updated (the old internal `thing` state will continue to be used).

To fix this, you can use an aggregate key of of the index + value (e.g. `` <div key={`${elem}_${i}`}> ``) or another value that properly differentiates items in your array.